# How to open an url from macOS/objc app and move the focus to browser?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I would like to open an url in a respective default app/browser from my app when a user clicks on a button. The opened web page should get focus.

I have found

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] 
    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com"]];
```

but it opens the page at the background (at least if Safari is already running). The browser will just "blicks" and keeps to be visible for a few miliseconds and than go into the background.

I have also tried `NSApplication sharedApplication` but this did nothing - it did not even opened the web page at all.

What to call so that the Safari will also get focus? Or at least notify the user visually that something happened in Safari.

Or do I need to follow another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSWorkspace openURL should just do it all correctly. If it doesn't, I'd look if your app does anything that might undo Safari being frontmost, like calling orderFront on one of your windows.

NSApplication openURL is for the case where you implement a browser of your own (or another app that handles a URL scheme), so it's not surprising that it doesn't do anything.

Other things you can look into if you want to bring an application to the front are NSRunningApplication and Launch services, but I'm a bit surprised that the browser doesn't come to front for you.

Or it could be related to this option in Safari preferences:
[image: Safari Tabs Preferences]
If toggling this setting (which is off on a newly-installed Mac) fixes your issue, you may need to use NSRunningApplication to bring Safari to the front explicitly.

Comment: I have dig it a bit and the issue seems to be related with an alert dialog. If I run the `openUrl` method directly, it works as expected. If I run it inside the `[alert runModel]` if clause, it triggers the issue of loosing the focus.

       `NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];`
       `[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Open web"];`
    
       `if ([alert runModal] == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {`
           `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] 
    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com"]];`
       `}`

Comment: Hmm, not everywhere it repro with the alert dialog. However, where it repros, the issue disappears if I do not show the dialog.

Comment: I have rewritten the code to use beginSheetModalForWindow and the issue disappears. I have no idea why.

Comment: AFAIK, when you close a dialog window, Cocoa brings your application's next window to the front, which implicitly brings to front your application. Since the URL opening happens asynchronously, that switches out Safari again before it has actually opened the window (or maybe right after, doesn't really matter). OTOH when you show a sheet, the parent window is already there and frontmost, so when the sheet closes, Cocoa doesn't think it has to bring it to front.

Comment: I see. So that means that the dialog is not closed/hidden yet when the runModal call returns? Do you have a tip for a reason of closing/hiding it later on instead of as part of the runModal call?